# Making a checkbox clickable in a large section

Tags: html, ionic2

I'm developing an ionic2 application and having a checkbox inside a button that i would like it to be checked when a user clicks anywhere on the button

This is what I've tried

```
  <label>
     <button ion-button clear small color="primary" icon-left >
         <input type='radio'> //radio btn inside the button
         <ion-icon name='share-alt'></ion-icon>
         Yes
     </button>
  </label>
```

The above fails what could be wrong?

Comment: What is the behavior you are getting and where is the event?